# Upgrading IIS 5.1 To IIS 6 on Windows XP

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-xp, iis-5

Is it possible to update IIS on Windows XP from 5.1 to 6?

If so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The version of IIS is tied to a specific version of Windows.

```
XP = IIS 5.1
2003 = IIS 6
2008 = IIS 7
```

More information available at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224609.

Comment: IIS Express 7.5 is now the way to go http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/901/iis-express-faq/

Comment: @GeekyMonkey is right. IIS Express 7.5 is supported on Windows XP SP3 and many other platforms as well. But you'll need development tools (WebMatrix or VisualStudio) to manage it because it desn't have the management console like the normal IIS does.

Answer (score 14):

It is now possible to Run IIS 7 - Express on XP, this is a full iis for developing but not deploying web applications.

see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx

Answer (score 3):

No, I believe it is just for Win2003 and x64 XP Pro

Answer (score 1):

it is possible if you have XP x64 Pro